# Pivot long format to wide without ID column

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following data in a long format:

```r
dt <- data.table(name = rep(c('A1','A2','A3'),3), value = rnorm(9))
```

I'm looking to transform `dt` to a wide format table, where `name` would correspond to column names, and `value` would correspond to the column values. I do not have the `id` column to assign, but we can assume that the entries in `dt` are ordered (i.e., the first row should contain the first 3 vertical entries in my example).

I'm looking for something similar to `tidyr:::pivot_wider(dt, names_from = 'name', values_from = 'value')`, but would prefer if the solution would not use any tidyverse package and stick to `data.frame` (or, preferably, `data.table`).

Are there any straightforward solutions already existing, or will I need to generate the ID's and use `dcast`? In other words, do we have anything simpler (or alternative) than the following:

```r
ncol <- length(unique(dt$name))
dt$ID <- rep(1:ncol, each = nrow(dt)/ncol)
dcast(dt, ID ~ name, value.var = 'value')
```

Comment: Possibly relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314356/dcast-with-empty-rhs

Comment: @user438383 Excellent, ``rowid(name) ~ name``, thanks!

Comment: With base R:  `unstack(dt, value ~ name)`